# Would a question about the relationship between a book and its video game be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Let us take the book series *TombQuest*, by Michael Northrop. This book series is published by Scholastic, and they have [a website for it](http://tombquest.scholastic.com). This series is a multiplatform, which means that there is a game associated with it. Like [the-39-clues](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-39-clues) (which is also a multiplatform). In that game, the connection is obvious - you hunt for the clues. And in another multiplatform, *Infinity Ring*, the connection is even more obvious - the game is part of the story, and each book picks up where the game left off, and vice versa. However, I'm having trouble finding a connection between the book *TombQuest* and its video game counterpart. In the book, the main characters have to

> Fight a group called the 'Death Walkers',

And in the game, you have to build your tomb, and invade other players tombs, avoiding their traps, and try to steal their treasure. However, I don't see how they are connected. Then again, I've only read the first book (and I haven't played in a looong time. I was, however, one of the fifty beta testers for the game).

Is there any connection?

---

## Would a question such as the above be on topic?

Comment: Is this related to the recent [Assassin's Creed question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2064/why-dont-the-assassins-creed-novels-include-present-day-events) and the [related meta](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/607/should-this-question-about-the-assassins-creed-novelization-be-downvoted)? It appears to me that community is pretty much for it.

Comment: No, not related. This is different - TombQuest game is not novelized (AFAIK) and the book is a book.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - that was actually part of the example question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

It's about a book, even if it's about something else as well. Even if the answer is no, that's a statement about the book series, and proving it requires knowledge of the book series. Books are literature.

See also: [Should we accept questions asking to compare a book and its adaptation?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/17)

Comment: Well, I know it hasn't been long, but I felt confident enough to [post it](http://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2079/58). Let's see how it goes...